# Terminate xeno SAX parser early

Tags: xml, haskell, sax

[xeno](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xeno) is a fast XML parsing library. It's SAX-style parsing function has the following type:

```hs
process
  :: Monad m
  => (ByteString -> m ()) -- ^ Open tag.
  -> (ByteString -> ByteString -> m ()) -- ^ Tag attribute.
  -> (ByteString -> m ()) -- ^ End open tag.
  -> (ByteString -> m ()) -- ^ Text.
  -> (ByteString -> m ()) -- ^ Close tag.
  -> (ByteString -> m ()) -- ^ CDATA.
  -> ByteString
  -> m ()
```

Is there is a choice of `m` that would allow to terminate `process` early from within a handler? By terminate early I mean `process` exits without processing the rest of the document i.e. no additional work.

I'm aware it can be done using IO and exceptions. Can it be done in IO without using exceptions for control flow? Can it be done without IO?

From the type above can we even tell for sure or would we also need to know the definition of `process`?

**Edit:**

Please assume `m` needs to support state and that state needs to be available after short-circuiting.

Comment: It certainly can be done. There are a lot of distinct options in the solution space, though. What information do you want to have after it completes, normally or via short-circuit?

Comment: @Carl I would like `m` to store some state and retrieve that state after it short circuits. Should have made that clear probably. If it makes things simpler lets assume I want to find the first node with a certain name, read all the values of it's attributes and then terminate and have a `Map ByteString ByteString` of the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know for sure just from the type signature of `process`, without seeing its implementation: the answer is unequivocally "yes, you can cause it to terminate early". [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT) is the canonical early-exit monad transformer family. Use [`throwE`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:throwE) or [`throwError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:throwError) to terminate control flow immediately.

Comment: Thanks! Finally figured it out. Indeed `(MonadState ParseState m, MonadError ParseException m)` seems to do the job nicely and I can run it purely using a simple combination of `runExceptT` and `runState`.